# Should viewport meta tag be modified to avoid Small Zoom applied by smartphones?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, mozilla

I am developing a responsive website and I have doubts about the following statement related to [viewport meta tag from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag):

> Suppress the small zoom applied by many smartphones by setting the
> initial scale and minimum-scale values to 0.86. The result is
> horizontal scroll is suppressed in any orientation and the user can
> zoom in if they want to.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.86">
```

Does this mean that responsive web pages should have this line to avoid possible small zooms in some smartphone, as Mozilla states in the link above?

I am asking because for me it is working initial-scale=1, but I see that in this link changes the scale. I actually see that most of people use scale 1, but did not find many cases using this 0.86 scale, which would make sense for me as I would like to avoid this possible zoom. Am I missing something?

Thanks!